# How does the process for evicting a tenant from privately owned student halls differ from standard privately rented accommodation?

Tags: england-and-wales, eviction, students

Many student halls are privately owned by for profit businesses. If a student renting a flat from a student only hall fails to leave at the end of a fixed term, is a possession order required to evict them?